# DRF - from django.conf.urls import url in Django 4.0

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've a project in django 3.2 and I've updated (pip install -r requirements.txt) to version 4.0 (new release) and I've currently the below error when I run the server in a virtual environment. I use DRF.

Can't import => from rest_framework import routers in urls.py

`from django.conf.urls import url ImportError: cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#url):

> url(regex, view, kwargs=None, name=None)¶
> This function is an alias to django.urls.re_path().

> Deprecated since version 3.1:
> Alias of django.urls.re_path() for backwards compatibility.

`django.conf.urls.url()` was deprecated since Django 3.1, and as per the release notes [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/internals/deprecation/), is removed in Django 4.0+.

You can resolve the issue using `path` or `re_path`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urls/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the error is coming from this line "from rest_framework import routers", when I import it. This error is in DRF, in the file router.py. I use path for ordinary urls.  File "/home/python/django/django/back/virtual_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 19, in <module>
    from django.conf.urls import url

Comment: Which version of rest_framework are you using?

Comment: The last one, with this command "pip install djangorestframework". if you see DRF documentation django 4.0 is suported (Django (2.2, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 4.0), and "from rest_framework import routers" is required.

Comment: @jga It will be helpful it you can provide the full traceback. As I can't find any reference to url in rest_framework router source code.

Comment: @jga Also try to provide the exact version number of rest_framework you have installed, using pip freeze.

Comment: solved, it was the version, djangorestframework==3.11.1, thanks